# Help about GoogleAdView.jar

Tags: android, adsense

Having noted this question has gone unanswered after a month, I hope I can meet with more success than this guy: -
[Help about GoogleAdView.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087026/help-about-googleadview-jar)

The instructions on http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/ states this: -

Integrating the Google Ads SDK with your Android-based app is a relatively straightforward process:
Add GoogleAdView.jar to your project's /libs directory. If you are developing in Eclipse, you will also need to add this JAR to your project's build path.

But, I do not have the file "GoogleAdView.jar" in the SDK - nor on my hard-drive anywhere for that matter, nor can I find it on the android SDK downloads or updates.  I've searched for a couple of hours now for it with no luck.  I am stumped before I even got a chance to start!  I have an Adsense account, and am pretty sure I am doing everything right.

I live in Australia if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question is here: -

http://google.com/support/forum/p/AdSense/thread?tid=0d0fe53ca006d699

Currently the AdSense SDK for Android is in Beta only, and seems to only be available in the USA.

A working solution in my case was to go with AdMob http://www.admob.com
and the instructions to get you started can be found here http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android

One thing that Wiki didn't make obvious was where the "Sites & Apps" tab is; you first have to click the "Marketplace" button at the very top of the browser - once you are logged in with an account with them that is.
Also note this is still a Google solution.